# How to sort a list of names based on substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

Say I have a file containing:

```
file1-01.json
file2-01.json
file3-01.json
file1-932.wav
file2-931.wav
file3-444.wav
file1-something.mp3
file2-something.mp3
file3-something.mp3
```

How can I turn it into:

```
file1-01.json
file1-932.wav
file1-something.mp3
file2-01.json
file2-931.wav
etc...
```

Code:

```
final_list = []

for i in line:
    basename = i.split(-)[0]
    group = [s for s in line if basename in s]
    final_list.append(group)
```

This approach seems a bit clunky when it comes to dealing with a huge file. any other efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I suggest you read the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the substring you have is the first one, just using `sorted` will do the job:

```
print(sorted(my_list))
```

returns:

```
['file1-01.json',
 'file1-932.wav',
 'file1-something.mp3',
 'file2-01.json',
 'file2-931.wav',
 'file2-something.mp3',
 'file3-01.json',
 'file3-444.wav',
 'file3-something.mp3']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
sorted_list = sorted(line, key=lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
```